# How to find out which interface am I using for connecting to the internet?

Tags: linux, routing

I have `eth0` and `wlan0` according to `ifconfig` and I can `ping google.com`.

How can I find out (with a normal user, not `root`) what interface is **active**, as in, what interface did the ping (or whatever, ping is not mandatory) use?

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 or Fedora 14

Comment: The below solutions seem to want you to do the inferring yourself, which doesn't seem right.  (And everybody's routing tables look incredibly straightforward!)  While I'm looking for the Windows equivalent, it appears that "ip route get <ip-address>" will tell you which interface _would_ be used if you were to attempt to connect to a given ip address.

Comment: Related on Server Fault: [Find interface for route to specific host](https://serverfault.com/a/644936/313521) (which is what I was looking for when I wound up here).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use `route` to find your default route:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

The `Iface` column in the line with destination `default` tells you which interface is used.

Comment: On Debian at least you need to do `/sbin/route`.

Comment: @Faheem Because `/sbin` isn't in normal users' PATH environ. This is pretty standard in most distros, even though it's generally one of the first things sysadmins alter for their 'main' user.

Comment: @Shadur: that's not the case in Fedora (as of FC13 if I remember correctly)

Comment: @Job in case we have an IP address how can we find which interface it uses.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. 
If iproute have been used to define custom routing rules ``route`` can't be used.
@Torgeir have the wright answer.

Comment: This answer is not correct. For example (and given the same routes displayed in the answer), if you ping 192.168.1.16 (a pc on your local network), the entry which starts with `192.168.1.0...` is the route that will be used. Of course in this case it refers to the same Iface, but that is just because you have one interface on your machine.

Comment: @kdehairy: That's correct. However, the original answer asked about which interface would be used when pinging `google.com` and I'm pretty sure that's not going to be on the local network :-)

Comment: @Job Even with google.com, if you have two routes each on a different interface, the match with the longer mask will be picked (not necessarily the default). All what default means, is that _if no other route is found, let's consult this one_ :)

Comment: I get a line "default ... eth0" and a line "default ... wlan0".  So which one is the real default?

Comment: I have same question "I get a line "default ... eth0" and a line "default ... wlan0". So which one is the real default?"

Comment: This doesn't work on mac OS.

Comment: There could be multiple "defaults" if multiple NICs of a single server/pc are plugged into a switch wired to the gateway.

Answer (score 50):

My version which is basically based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14967) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727242):

```
route | grep '^default' | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
```

And this, *experimentally*, for macOS:

```
route -n get default | grep 'interface:' | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
```

Comment: is there a way for you to translate this for OSX?

Comment: @JohnAllard: let me know if my update now gives correct answer there for macOS.

Comment: you don't need multiple pipes, just use `route |awk '/^default/{print $NF}'`

Comment: I get two lines: "eth0" and "wlan0", so I still don't know which one is active...

Comment: The mac OS suggestion worked for me, thanks!  In my case, "netstat -rn" lists two default interfaces, since the machine has a wired and a wifi interface.  It was useful to confirm which one has precedence.

Comment: I know it has been said in the comments, but I think the answer should be edited to warn that these commands will sometimes output two lines (ex if there are multiple connections such as via ethernet and wifi). If someone's not expecting this and uses it in a script, could cause problems.

Comment: There could be multiple "defaults" if multiple NICs of a single server/pc are plugged into a switch wired to the gateway

Answer (score 31):

On GNU/Linux systems:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# host we want to "reach"
host=google.com

# get the ip of that host (works with dns and /etc/hosts. In case we get  
# multiple IP addresses, we just want one of them
host_ip=$(getent ahosts "$host" | awk '{print $1; exit}')
    
# only list the interface used to reach a specific host/IP. We only want the part
# between dev and the remainder (use grep for that)
ip route get "$host_ip" | grep -Po '(?<=(dev ))(\S+)'
```

Comment: Please explain what these commands are doing. Also, you're probably pretty safe here, because you know what your values are, but, generally, you should quote shell variables references (unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing).

Comment: Done, to some extent. Only posted this because I could not find anything that did exactly this. Am using this as a custom fact in a puppet manifest...

Comment: Your answer is more correct if the `host` is an input argument to the script. As the route (and hence the interface) might be different for different ips.

Comment: My slight adjustment to the `grep` part: `grep -Po '(?<= dev ).+?(?= (src|proto))'`

Answer (score 23):

One liner:

`ip route get 8.8.8.8 | sed -n 's/.*dev \([^\ ]*\).*/\1/p'`

Comment: There's a dangling quote there. Doesn't work at all as-is

Comment: @Krease Author updated his answer

Comment: @MarinosAn I guess it depends of the system... I needed to modify your snippet to used `print $5` instead of `print $3`...

Comment: @billy It would be good to provide your OS to keep here as a reference.

Comment: @MarinosAn Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @billy You are right. I had a typo. `print $5` works for me also. Fixing/replacing my initial comment with the one below..

Comment: +1 for the `ip route get 8.8.8.8`, the rest doesn't work on **ubuntu 18.04**. I used something simpler: `ip route get 8.8.8.8 | head -n1 | awk '{print $5}'`

Comment: `ip route get 1.1.1.1 | head -n1 | awk '{print $5}'` for CloudFlare works too... FYI `8.8.8.8` is the Google-controlled DNS service.

Comment: didn't work, no output on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Update should work on most linux's now

Answer (score 15):

Get the default network interface typically used to route to the "remaining" internet in opposite to DMZ, private network, VM host etc. which are usually routed explicitly.

```
$ ip route get 8.8.8.8 | sed -n 's/.* dev \([^\ ]*\) .*/\1/p'
eth0
```

Comment: it is not always the default route that gets you to where you want. Although the OP most probably is using the default route to get to the internet, this is a generalization and might not always hold true. A word of caution

Comment: Sure, it is only default network interface. If there are multiple connections, one should not really speak about "connecting to the internet", but rather about network interface used for routing to the exact destination.

Comment: You do not need to use multiple pipes/greps , `ip -4 route ls  |awk '/^default/{print $5}'`

Comment: There could be multiple "defaults" if multiple NICs of a single server/pc are plugged into a switch wired to the gateway

Comment: @DanglingPointer fixed. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 11):

Different distros of Linux, Unix, some versions of Microsoft Windows, and many other Operating Systems are not limited  to using just one network interface to reach the internet. 
Many Operating Systems will detect more than one valid interface, capable of reaching the internet, and set up each of them for carrying traffic to the internet (specifically, gateways that ultimately connect to the internet).

If the OS tries to reach an external network and succeeds using `eth0`, it will add that interface to the routing table and tie it to that network. 
If the OS tries to reach the same external network
and also succeeds using `eth1`,
it will also add that interface (`eth1`) into the routing table
as an additional way to reach that same network. 
Other posters thus far have not considered the importance of the metric values in a routing table.

My routing table, below, shows two different interfaces, `eth0` and `wlan0`. 
Both are up, both have been set automatically by the operating system as default routes to the gateway `192.168.1.1`,
and both have had a route built automatically by the operating system
to the `192.168.1.X` (i.e., `192.168.1.0/24`) network. 
This entire routing table was written automatically by the OS. 
No edits to it were made by me. The difference shown here is that
the wired ethernet interface (`eth0`) has a lower metric (202),
and thus more of my traffic to nodes beyond my own network
will be routed through this interface (it is preferred by the lower metric),
while the remainder of my traffic to nodes beyond my network
will be routed through the wireless interface (`wlan0`)
(it has a higher metric of 303, and thus is less preferred by the OS).

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

Both interfaces are being used to reach "the internet", and their use is weighted by the "Metric" values, as can be seen in the bytes and packets statistics for `eth0` and `wlan0` below:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip -s address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    0          0        0       0       0       0       
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    0          0        0       0       0       0       
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:31:a2:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.195/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 80787sec preferred_lft 69987sec
    inet6 fe80::2f3f:3f1d:8c35:a05e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    14341060   22393    0       0       0       971                             ←—— high
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    1190274    10745    0       0       0       0                               ←—— high
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:31:a2:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.193/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 80787sec preferred_lft 69987sec
    inet6 fe80::4f31:5fcf:8f70:b5ca/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    4963408    7954     0       0       0       929                             ←—— lower
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    49371      235      0       0       0       0                               ←—— lower
```

As the annotations indicate, `eth0` is being given more traffic by the OS.

Many Operating Systems will give a lower metric to a wired interface that has a faster connection,
and a higher metric to a wired interface with a slower connection. 
For example, if `eth0` and `eth1` both connect to the same node,
but `eth0` negotiated a 100 Mbs connection,
and `eth1` negotiated only a 10 Mbs connection,
`eth0` would be given a lower metric than `eth1`. 
Similarly, many Operating Systems will give a lower metric to a wired interface, and a higher metric to a wireless interface.

More than one interface can be set up automatically (depending on the OS),
or manually, to reach the same external node by making/editing entries to the routing table.

---

A minimally tested script to find the interface with the lowest metric
as reported by `route`: <sub><sup>[Added by G-Man]</sup></sub>

```
route | awk '
        BEGIN           { min = -1 }
        $1 == "default" {
                            if (min < 0  ||  $5 < min) {
                                min   = $5
                                iface = $8
                            }
                        }
        END             {
                            if (iface == "") {
                                print "No \"default\" route found!" > "/dev/stderr"
                                exit 1
                            } else {
                                print iface
                                exit 0
                            }
                        }
        '
```

You might want to extend this to look at the "Flags"; i.e., `$4`.

Comment: This would be the best answer here for those with multiple NICs, which I believe should be everyone here if they are asking the OP's question?

Answer (score 5):

Running `ifconfig` will give you the information you need.

The active interface will have an `inet addr` and will show a record of transmitted data, like so:

```
RX bytes:1930741 (1.8 Mb)  TX bytes:204768 (199.9 Kb)
```

You can also use the `ip addr` command and any inactive interfaces will be designated as having: `NO-CARRIER`.

Comment: Since OP doesn't want to be root, maybe you should give full path to the executable?

Comment: Neither command requires elevated privileges.

Comment: I checked that ifconfig runs ok with normal privileges, but on Debian (and I suppose Ubuntu), it's in /sbin, and that's not part of normal user path. Is your system different?

Comment: Ubuntu and Arch: both run with normal privileges (although on Ubuntu it is /sbin)

Comment: Neither `ifconfig` nor `route` requires privileges just to read out info, but both commands are in `/sbin` which isn't in the `PATH` environment of regular users by default. `ip` on the other hand is in `/bin`

Comment: @Shadur Not on my install of Ubuntu 10.10 and according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables the default $PATH is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:`

Comment: This won't necessarily help on a system with multiple interfaces, as the poster indicated having.  A better answer is using the `route` command though that wouldn't necessarily be foolproof either due to routing.  The default route does not have to be the one to get to the Internet though it may often be.

Answer (score 5):

The command `ip route ls` will give a list of active routes and their sources:

```
caleburn: ~/ >ip route ls
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.7 
default via 192.168.10.254 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this command:

```
$ route | grep default | awk '{print $8}'
enp0s3
```

Comment: [root@linux1 network-scripts]# route|grep default | awk '{print $8}'
enp0s3
[root@linux1 network-scripts]#

Comment: Useless use of grep :)   awk ‘/default/{print $8}’

Comment: There could be multiple "defaults" if multiple NICs of a single server/pc are plugged into a switch wired to the gateway

Answer (score 1):

```
Debian: apt-get install net-tools
Alpine: apk add net-tools
Arch Linux: pacman -S net-tools
CentOS: yum install net-tools
Fedora: dnf install net-tools
```

```
route | head -3 | tail -1 | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f8
```

---

```
Debian: apt-get install iproute2
Alpine: apk add iproute2
Arch Linux: pacman -S iproute2
CentOS: yum install iproute2
Fedora: dnf install iproute2
OS X: brew install iproute2
```

```
ip route | head -1 | cut -d " " -f5
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. Please consider adding some text to explain what each block of code / commands means. Although useful, your answer might be hard to understand for unexperienced users

Answer (score 0):

If your machine has multiple interfaces (which I assume), there is no one interface that will be used for connecting to the internet.

Depending on the destination you are connecting to, your system will consult the ip table (the one shown when you do `route` command) to find the next hope/router, when it does find one, it will use the interface associated with it.

That said, please refer to @torgeir's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165067/284398) as it does exactly that:

1. Given a domain (hardcoded as google.com, which is the only bad point in the answer)
2. Resolves it's ip
3. Consults the ip table for the route to use (and hence the interface).

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter one liner:
`ip route show default | cut -d " " -f 5`

or

`ip route show default | sed -n 's/.* dev \([^\ ]*\) .*/\1/p'`