# Unable to access internet if wireless enabled

Tags: networking, routing

The following is my route output. `eth0` is my wired network and `eth1` is my wireless network. Only wired one has access to internet. If I enable wireless, I am not able to access internet, it tries to access via `eth1` and I get 404 page of the wireless router. Why does `eth1` have higher preference though default is `eth0` [(link)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14961/how-to-find-out-which-interface-am-i-using-for-connecting-to-the-internet)?

```
[balakrishnan@mylap ~]$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.26.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.26.0.0       *               255.255.192.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 eth1


[balakrishnan@mylap ~]$ tracepath -n 8.8.8.8
 1:  10.26.21.101                                          0.098ms pmtu 1500
 1:  10.26.0.1                                            35.519ms 
 1:  10.26.0.1                                            29.763ms 
 2:  113.193.0.209                                        29.718ms 
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply
```

**Edit:** I noticed that some times (rarely) I am able to connect. It looks like it randomly tries on both interfaces. Is there a way to set to use only eth0 ?

Comment: The default gateway is out eth0 via 10.26.0.1. Can you provide the output of `tracepath -n 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Updated with output. It doesn't end. I keep getting no reply

Comment: Your default route is definitely over the wired connection... Are you sure you can't get to the Internet? You are trying more than just a web browser, correct? Are there proxy settings in the browser's configuration? Operating system? Steps you've already taken to resolve the issue?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.10. Tried with both firefox and chrome. sometimes it opens. When I refresh, it goes away. With disabling wireless, it is always stable. No proxy settings configured anywhere. I tried `ping google.com` from terminal which doesn't work too.

Comment: ping works now again for some websites. Some services work, others dont. wget works fine. dropbox works. apt-get doesn't work, both browsers don't work.

Comment: What happens if you change the IP address for the eth1 to a different network, say 192.168.12.0?

Comment: tried changing ip. Didn't work