# How to find out the interface which is being used for internet?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, routing

I have multiple network interfaces and I am not sure which interface is being used for the internet connection.

I tried the methods which are listed in the question [How to find out which interface am I using for connecting to the internet?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14961/277542), howerver I'm getting multiple "default" network interfaces when I use suggested solutions.

[image: output of route]

Comment: Look at the metric.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, as per the wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrics_(networking), "The route will go in the direction of the gateway with the lowest metric" (here the interface (ens6) which have 0 metrics), so the answer is ens6?

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for ipv4:

```
ip -o route get 8/8 | grep --color=always 'dev [^ ]*'
```

for ipv6:

```
ip -o route get 2000::/3 | grep --color=always 'dev [^ ]*'
```